# Get a clicked HTML Cell Value in VBScript

Tags: vbscript, onclick, html-table, hta

I have been searching for nearly an hour now and still no closer to an answer. Basically - I want to click on a HTML Cell, and get the current value of that HTML cell, and assign that value to a VBScript Variable. Honestly, if someone could tell me how to do the first bit, i'd be happy. Like this, only in VBScript - [Get HTML table cells values in a rows by clicking on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051821/get-html-table-cells-values-in-a-rows-by-clicking-on-it).

The only issue here is that the table is being generated, in full, eariler in the script and then placed in a Span tag.

Any help would be vastly appricated.

Edit: OK so heres what im running now. Been banging my head for over an hour now:

```
    Sub Display_Click
Dim conn, str1
MainTitle.InnerHTML = "<h2>Main Call Queue</h2>"
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Open "DSN=Login"
Set rsData = conn.Execute("SELECT * FROM MainTable WHERE CallStat='Open' ORDER BY P_ID DESC;")
str1 = "<table border=1 cellpadding=5><tr><th>Call Id</th><th>Full Name</th><th>Postcode</th><th>Site Code</th><th>Problem Title</th><th>Category</th><th>SubCategory</th><th>Call Status</th></tr>"
Do Until rsData.EOF = True
str1 = str1 & "<tr onClick=" & chr(34) & "Cell ME" & chr(34) & "><td>" & rsData("P_Id") & "</td><td>" & rsData("FirstN") & "</td><td>" & rsData("PostCode") & "</td><td>" & rsData("SiteNumber") & "</td><td>" & rsData("PTitle") & "</td><td>" & rsData("PCat") & "</td><td>" & rsData("SCat") & "</td><td>" & rsData("CallStat") & "</td></tr>"
rsData.moveNext
Loop
str1 = str1 & "</table>"
MainDisplay.InnerHTML = str1
conn.Close
Call CheckState
End Sub
```

Im convienced the error lies somewhere in this block. Table generates with the 3 rows, and i get the error 3 times.

Comment: OK - an update to the above, in my table I have added a 'onclick = ' tag to the <td>, would this help? And if so, what do I put in the tag? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you influence the generated elements (so that they're generated with additional attributes)? If so, something like the following should work.

**VBscript:**

```
Sub Foo(obj)
  MsgBox obj.innerHtml
End Sub
```

**HTML:**

```
<table id="tableID">
  <tr>
    <td onClick="Foo Me">row 1, cell 1</td>
    <td onClick="Foo Me">row 1, cell 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td onClick="Foo Me">row 2, cell 1</td>
    <td onClick="Foo Me">row 2, cell 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The attribute `onClick="..."` adds a procedure or function for handling click events to a tag. `Foo()` is a procedure that takes one argument (`obj`). `Me` is a reference to the object in which the click event occurred (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa141658)). The call `Foo Me` passes the reference to the `<td>` element to the procedure `Foo`, so that the procedure effectively runs `MsgBox Me.innerHtml`.

Comment: Right - ok, that didnt make much sence to me, but I also see what your getting at. How would the "onclick =" work and how does it relate to the Sub? The in the Sub the (obj) part? I'm guessing these are all variables?

Comment: Ah!! I get it now, didnt reliase the "me" part was the event. Ok, let me try this ang get back to you. Shouldnt be too long.

Comment: Ok, i think I nearly have this working. How would I go abut putting this into an variable string, I done the following: but its not really working: `str1 = str1 & "<tr><td onclick=" & chr(34) & "OnCallID Me" & chr(34) & ">" & rsData("P_Id")` ect ect. I just click it, and nothing happens... any ideas? Also - would this work if the table was in a <span> tag?

Comment: I've really broken it now, im getting an error message: `Line 1, Char 10, expected ";"` What the fudge? I wasnt any where near that line, so I guess ive gone and broken it completely... any ideas?

Comment: Nesting the table in a `<span>` tag shouldn't pose a problem. Can't help you with generating the table right now, though. Perhaps I'll be able to come up with something when I get home tonight.

Comment: For help with that error you'll have to post your code. I'm neither sitting in front of your computer, nor am I psychic.

Comment: I don't see anything in the posted code that would warrant an `expected ";"` error. Did you perhaps put that procedure in a `<script language="JScript">` block? That would explain the error. As for generating the table, use single quotes for the attributes instead of concatenating `Chr(34)` that makes building the string a *lot* less error-prone (`"<tr onClick='Cell Me'><td>" & ...`.

Comment: Right, well, it's defo that `onclick='Cell Me'` which is breaking the code. Is there any other way of doing it?

Comment: I just double checked to see if there might be a problem with the procedure name, but it works just fine in my test HTA, so I suspect the cause of the issue is somewhere else in your HTA.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the `chr(34)` and insert a function after the `onClick` to store the value.

```
"onClick = function()" not chr(34) & "Cell Me" & Chr(34)
```