# HTA with dynamically generated HTML Tables with onclick faults

Tags: vbscript, onclick, html-table, hta

Right. I need help here. I have a HTA, and it runs completely fine. UNTIL I do the following to my code. I am working with VBScript. Code below:

```
<Script language="vbscript">

Sub DisplayDB_Click
  Dim conn, str1, str2
  str2 = "Hello"
  MainTitle.InnerHTML = "<h2>Main Call Queue</h2>"
  Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
  conn.Open "DSN=LongbowLogin"
  Set rsData = conn.Execute("SELECT * FROM MainTable WHERE CallStat='Open' ORDER BY P_ID DESC;")
  str1 = "<table border=1 cellpadding=5><tr><th>Call Id</th><th>Full Name</th><th>Postcode</th><th>Site Code</th><th>Problem Title</th><th>Category</th><th>SubCategory</th><th>Call Status</th></tr>"
  Do Until rsData.EOF = True
    str1 = str1 & "<tr><td onclick=msgbox(str2)>" & rsData("P_Id") & "</td><td>" & rsData("FirstN") & "</td><td>" & rsData("PostCode") & "</td><td>" & rsData("SiteNumber") & "</td><td>" & rsData("PTitle") & "</td><td>" & rsData("PCat") & "</td><td>" & rsData("SCat") & "</td><td>" & rsData("CallStat") & "</td></tr>"
    rsData.moveNext
  Loop
  str1 = str1 & "</table>"
  MainDisplay.InnerHTML = str1
  conn.Close
  Call CheckState
End Sub
```

This code makes a HTML Table out of a SQL Select Statement and places it in a Span tag named `MainDisplay` under `InnerHTML`. This part works beautifully. However - After I add the
`< td onclick='msgbox(str2)' >` part, it will not work.

I click the first cell, and I get a message: `"Line 1, 'str2' is not defined."`.

I actually want it to say
`< td onClick='CellID Me') >` , `CellID` being a sub later in the same script block. I am doing this `msgbox` to troubleshoot.

`str2` clearly is defined, so I'm clearly missing something here...

Any help here would be great, I'm going mad...

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBScript does no variable interpolation:

```
>> Dim str2 : str2 = "I'm str2 and this is my content"
>> Dim sRes : sRes = "<td onclick=MsgBox str2></td>"
>> WScript.Echo sRes
>>
<td onclick=MsgBox str2></td>
```

You'll have to splice the content into the result - and follow VBScript's rules about parentheses and quotes:

```
>> Dim str2 : str2 = "I'm str2 and this is my content"
>> Dim sRes : sRes = "<td onclick='MsgBox """ & str2 & """'></td>"
>> WScript.Echo sRes
>>
<td onclick='MsgBox "I'm str2 and this is my content"'></td>
```

This explains your immediate problem. Your real world task - attach a onclick event handler to all TDs - is better solved by creating the table using the DOM (.createElement, appendChild) than by trying to tame string concatenations into .innerHTML.

Comment: Ok, I see your point, I think... I thought VBScript doesnt allow for 'WScript.Echo' commands? Also, could  you given an example how you would ue the DOM commands to do this? Many Thanks.

Comment: So is there anyway around this issue? What about *glup* using JavaScript? Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

To make the `MsgBox` work you'll have to change this:

```
"<tr><td onclick=msgbox(str2)>" & rsData("P_Id") & ...
```

into this:

```
"<tr><td onclick='msgbox(""" & str2 & """)'>" & rsData("P_Id") & ...
```

However, I already [told you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16771778/1630171) that the code

```
"<tr><td onclick='Cell Me'>" & rsData("P_Id") & ...
```

works in principle. I verified this with an HTA that creates a table from a CSV on button-click.

**VBScript:**

```
Sub DisplayDB_Click
  Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
  conn.Open "Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};" & _
    & "Dbq=c:\Temp;Extensions=asc,csv,tab,txt;"
  Set rsData = conn.Execute("SELECT * FROM sample.csv;")
  str1 = "<table border=1 cellpadding=5><tr>"
  For Each field In rsData.Fields
    str1 = str1 & "<th>" & field.Name & "</th>"
  Next
  str1 = str1 & "</tr>"
  Do Until rsData.EOF
    str1 = str1 & "<tr>"
    For Each field In rsData.Fields
      str1 = str1 & "<td onclick='Cell Me'>" & field.Value & "</td>"
    Next
    str1 = str1 & "<tr>"
    rsData.moveNext
  Loop
  str1 = str1 & "</table>"
  MainDisplay.InnerHTML = str1
  conn.Close
End Sub

Sub Cell(obj)
  MsgBox obj.innerHtml
End Sub
```

**HTML:**

```
<p><input type="button" onClick="DisplayDB_Click" value="Show Table"/></p>
<div id="MainDisplay"></div>
```

If this code doesn't work for you, the issue is somewhere else in the HTA.

---

As [Ekkehard.Horner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16793496/1630171) suggested, the table could also be created using `createElement` and `appendChild`, e.g. like this:

```
Sub Cell
  MsgBox Me.innerHtml
End Sub

Function NewField(text, isHeader)
  If isHeader Then
    Set e = document.createElement("th")
  Else
    Set e = document.createElement("td")
  End If
  e.AppendChild document.createTextNode(text)
  e.onClick = GetRef("Cell")
  Set NewField = e
End Function

Function NewRow(values, isHeader)
  Set r = document.createElement("tr")
  For Each v In values
    r.appendChild NewField(v, isHeader)
  Next
  Set NewRow = r
End Function

Sub DisplayDB_Click
  ...

  lastCol = rsData.Fields.Count-1
  Dim cols
  ReDim cols(lastCol)

  For i = 0 To lastCol
    cols(i) = rsData.Fields(i).Name
  Next

  Set thead = document.createElement("thead")
  thead.appendChild NewRow(cols, True)

  Set tbody = document.createElement("tbody")
  Do Until rsData.EOF
    For i = 0 To LastCol
      cols(i) = rsData.Fields(i).Value
    Next
    tbody.appendChild NewRow(cols, False)
    rsData.MoveNext
  Loop

  Set table = document.createElement("table")
  table.appendChild thead
  table.appendChild tbody
  document.getElementById("parent").appendChild table

  ...
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok - above, you use a Div tag, I am using a Span tag, is there any difference?

Comment: Right, ok, I'm going to give up this. I can not get this working. It carrys on saying "Expected ";". I have no idea if its interacting for MySql statements badly, or what. I've taken the new way of doing the table, the `For Each field` part as it works alot nicer - Thanks for that. I've put a workaround in place. Its not as pretty, but it works. Shame... anywho, onwards.

Comment: `<div>` is a block-level element whereas `<span>` is an inline element (which shouldn't be (ab)used as a block-level element). My sample code worked with both `<div>` and `<span>`, though. As for the `expected ";"` error: I already told you that it's probably caused by a `<script language="javascript">` or `<script>` block containing non-JavaScript code. For further troubleshooting you need to provide your full code of the HTA.