# Dynamically graph points with Highcharts

Tags: graph, highcharts

How can I dynamically graph points from a table? The table has two columns dedicated to the x and y coordinates and an additional column for duration.

### Example

Say I have the table shown below. The Date and Effort columns would compose the x,y coordinates (Timestamp, Effort) for a line chart. This line chart would have data-points based on cumulative totals from the Timestamp and Effort columns. The Duration column would determine how long the entry had an impact on the data-points of the line chart. So based on this table, I would want a line chart with the coordinates listed under Data-Points.

**Timestamp        Effort  Duration**

4/13/2016 12:13:12.15    10     100

4/13/2016 12:13:12.80    12     100

4/13/2016 12:13:13.15    30     100

4/13/2016 12:13:13.80    50     100

**Data-Points:**

(4/13/2016 12:13:12.15, 10) 

(4/13/2016 12:13:12.80, 22)

(4/13/2016 12:13:13.15, 42)

(4/13/2016 12:13:13.80, 80)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up preprocessing the data. First, I got all of the data points into the series cumulatively. Next, I updated the datetime x values with the durations. Finally, I subtracted each individual y value whose x value was less than the cumulative data point's x value.

Answer (score 1):

One of the Highcharts demos shows precisely how you can accomplish this using a static HTML table: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-parsed.

I've created a fiddle using your sample data and plotted it as a line chart, per your requirement: http://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/qgvkp0t0/

Your data table would be coded similar to the following:

```
<table id="datatable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Time</th>
      <th>Effort</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>4/13/2016 12:13:12.15</th>
      <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>4/13/2016 12:13:12.80</th>
      <td>22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>4/13/2016 12:13:13.15</th>
      <td>42</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>4/13/2016 12:13:13.80</th>
      <td>80</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You would then create your chart using the following code. Note the `data` attribute that calls to your HTML table's ID:

```
$(function () {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    data: {
      table: 'datatable'
    },
    chart: {
      type: 'line'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Data extracted from a HTML table in the page'
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: 'category'
    },
    yAxis: {
      allowDecimals: false,
      title: {
        text: 'Units'
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      formatter: function () {
        return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' + this.point.y;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

One thing to note: without any modifications, your timestamp data would be read into your x-axis as a `datetime` type. This would leave you with empty points for those dates or times in between.

In my example, I explicitly set the x-axis type to `category`, so that there is exactly one plot on the chart for each data point.

Now, to get the x-axis labels to appear in a more readable format, you can explore the `xAxis.labels.formatter` attribute (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.formatter) and the `Highcharts.dateFormat()` function (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.dateFormat).

> **Update (July 13, 2016)**: I've been able to solve the original poster's requirement of adding cumulative points based on data in an HTML table, but not the removal of dates that are older than the current data point's duration. My modifications are below.

In order to take the data from an HTML table and work with it prior to plotting the chart, I used the `data.columns` attribute (see http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#data.columns).

Before your chart options are declared, I wrote this code to go through the HTML table and add the content to arrays.

```
  // read through the HTML table and calculate cumulative effort
  // solution inspired by:
  // 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248869/how-do-i-get-data-from-a-data-table-in-javascript
  // 2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057226/how-to-get-html-table-td-cell-value-by-javascript

  // set the series name as the default; this is the first entry read by data.columns
  var seriesTime = ['Time'];
  var seriesEffort = ['Effort'];
  var seriesDuration = ['Duration'];

  var table = document.getElementById('datatable');
  var noRows = table.rows.length;

    // go through the table and assign values to the series arrays
  // start with the second row (r = 1) to omit the table's header
  for (var r = 1; r < noRows; r++) {
    seriesTime.push(Date.parse(table.rows[r].cells[0].innerHTML));
    seriesEffort.push(parseInt(table.rows[r].cells[1].innerHTML));
    seriesDuration.push(parseInt(table.rows[r].cells[2].innerHTML));
  }
```

I then use those arrays as follows:

```
data: {
  // refer to demo link at: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#data.columns
  columns: [
    seriesTime,         // categories
    seriesEffort        // first series
  ]
},
```

The way this works is that the first item expected in these arrays is the series name, which is why I have as the default value when the arrays are first declared.

Now, once you have the data in arrays, you would need to run through them to calculate your cumulative totals and subtract those whose duration has passed. Unfortunately, I wasn't successful on the duration piece. Here's what I wrote in my fiddle:

```
    // next, go through the series arrays and tally up the cumulative totals based on duration
  for (var t = 2; t < seriesTime.length; t++) {

    seriesEffort[t]+=seriesEffort[t-1];

    for (var e = 1; e < seriesEffort.length; e++) {
        if (seriesTime[e] < seriesTime[t] - seriesDuration[t]) {        // NOTE: this is where I'm getting stuck
        seriesEffort[t]-=seriesEffort[e];
      } else {
        //seriesEffort[t]+=seriesEffort[e];
      }

    }
  }
```

I hope this gets you closer to your solution. I apologize that I couldn't get this 100% mocked up for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that is not quite what I am looking for. The example you provide relies on you calculating the values and inputting them in td's. In my case, I want the data to be read in from the original table (with the "Timestamp," "Effort," and "Duration" columns) and calculated to get the data-points. As of right now, the only way I can think of how to graph the table in my desired way is to track the x-axis and have each value from the table subtracted from the cumulative total after their duration is complete. Do you know if there is a way to do this?

Comment: @ThanksInAdvance Ah, I see what you meant. Yes, I believe there's a way to do this. What's the calculation you're using to get the data point from your effort and duration columns? I'll be glad to update my answer accordingly.

Comment: (4/13/2016 12:13:12.15, 10) is the first point, which is fetched directly from the table (row 1). (4/13/2016 12:13:12.80, 22) is the second point because I add row 1's Effort value to row 2's Effort value, and since row 1 has a duration of 100 ms, it will continue to be factored into the total Effort value of the data-point until it expires (at 12:13:13.15). At that point, row 1's Effort value will be subtracted from the cumulative Effort value. This pattern continues all the way through until completion.

Comment: @ThanksInAdvance For your duration, what is 100? is that 100 milliseconds?

Comment: @ThanksInAdvance I've updated my answer above with more details on taking the values in the HTML table and setting them up for calculations. I was able to get the cumulative totals part working, but not the subtractions for the duration, unfortunately. I hope this at least gets you closer to your goal.